# net:: ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Flutter webview app on android 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: flutter, webview-flutter

I created a flutter webview application and successfully tested on many emulator android api versions & a physical device running on Android 11. Lastly when I'm testing on my **older android 6.0 device** , I got an error message as mentioned below.

```
The webpage https://testsite.com could not be loaded because
 net:: ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

[image: Photo of the error message]

If this error occurred to anybody / if anyone have solution for this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [article on internet](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/err_spdy_protocol_error) said that this "ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR" can occur due to outdated web browser. So I tried to update the chrome browser on my phone. But it didn't solve my problem.

Finally I made it worked by updating the **Android System WebView** on google playstore. I think the error earlier happened is because of the  **very old Android System WebView**.

[image: updating the Android System WebView]